# Chrome debugger React.js app displays white screen and load icon (tab bar) on refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, javascript-debugger

I am working on a react app that is causing me to have to open a new tab every time I use a debugger after making code changes.

Issue:

- When using Chrome and displaying the developer tools.
- I add a debugger to my code,
- I go back to chrome and reload react app
- I then trigger the event where the debugger is located,
- I can clearly see that the debugger stopped and is working. I do not press continue.
- I make any code change (add new lines) and save file.
- I go back to Chrome and reload app (hit `cmd + r` to refresh).

**What I see: I get white screen and app seems to be frozen.** 
[image: blank screen chrome react js]

**Additional info:**

- I tried it in firefox and it does work as intended.
- I am also using VSCode as my editor.
- Updated all packages to latest versions.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah I have that problem as well. I seems that sometimes if you reload the page while your website is stopped at some breakpoint, Chrome gets a bit crazy. But that is more an issue with chrome, not with your app.

Just try not to reload while a breakpoint is active.